# I want to remove duplicate object from Stack (Last in First out)

Tags: java, android, stack

I Hold list in Stack then when I press back button Stack is pop and give previous list but I have another Activity when I come back form Activity to list Activity last object add two time and this process is continue when I go List Activity to Activity .. My question is .....
How to remove duplicate object from stack ?

```
    stack.push(UnsobergamesApplication.combine);
  type = UnsobergamesApplication.combine.get(position).getType();
if (type == 0) {

                                                                 if(!UnsobergamesApplication.combine.isEmpty()) {
cat_id = UnsobergamesApplication.combine.get(position).getId();
//
                                                                     UnsobergamesApplication.combine = handler.getListbyId(String.valueOf(cat_id));
                                                                      Log.e("Combine list is..", UnsobergamesApplication.combine.toString());

  adapter = new Category_Adapter(SubCategoryActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, UnsobergamesApplication.combine);
//                                                                     adapter = new ArrayAdapter(SubCategoryActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, UnsobergamesApplication.combine);
                                                                         listView_Combine.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
      } else if (type == 1) {

    Log.e("next screen", String.valueOf(type));
                                                                UnsobergamesApplication.title_name = UnsobergamesApplication.combine.get(position).getName();
                                                                 UnsobergamesApplication.description = UnsobergamesApplication.combine.get(position).getDescription();

 Intent intent = new Intent(SubCategoryActivity.this,Details_Activity.class);
                                                                 startActivity(intent);
                                                                 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_up_out);
                                                             }
```

This is my code when i go SubCategoryActivity to Details_Activity nd then come back satck push dublicate obect . i wnat to remove dublicate obect from stack..

Comment: what you tried so far? paste your code

Answer (score 0):

Try set() method in you MainActivity.class?

Comment: actually i want to add concept of LIFO in list.

Comment: please suggest how to give condition or any other concept to prevent duplicate object